# Dropbox ZIP appears in Downloads folder

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, dropbox

I have a dropbox.zip file (2.7GB) appearing spontaneously in my Downloads folder on Kubuntu 16.04. I do not use Dropbox and I do not have Dropbox client installed. I can delete the file but it reappears after some time. Opening the file doesn't work, it seems to be corrupt.

Any idea where the file could come from?

Comment: Have you checked the downloads history of your browser?

Comment: Unfortunately the history is cleared, so I wouldn't see it if it came from there. In case it came from the browser (which would be plausible) how could it possible be that the file download starts automatically and is restored all the time without any request?

Comment: Because the download link is still open in one of the tabs???  **;-)**

Comment: Not it isn't. Also I would get new entries in the download history and I would get dialogs, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. KTorrent was downloading some file from an unknown source. I have no idea where it came from since I have never used torrent before. Anyway I removed KTorrent for good.

Comment: Why not just remove the torrent?

Comment: I just intended to never use KTorrent... so removing it was a valid solution.